# Hibernate Mapping Package

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm using Hibernate Annotations.

In all my model classes I annotate like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class SomeModelClass {
//
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
      <!-- some properties -->

      <mapping package="com.fooPackage" />
      <mapping class="com.fooPackage.SomeModelClass" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

For every class I add to the com.fooPackage I have to add a line in the hibernate.cfg.xml like this:

```
<mapping class="com.fooPackage.AnotherModelClass" />
```

Is there a way I can add new model classes but don't need to add this line to hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: It's worth commenting that the `<mapping package="com.fooPackage/>` entry is for configuring meta-data defined on the package itself, not for classes *in* that package.

Answer (score 18):

Out of the box - no. You can write your own code to detect / register your annotated classes, however. If you're using Spring, you can extend `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and do something like:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
  ArrayList<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

  // the following will detect all classes that are annotated as @Entity
  ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
    new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
  scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));

  // only register classes within "com.fooPackage" package
  for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.fooPackage")) {
    String name = bd.getBeanClassName();
    try {
      classes.add(Class.forName(name));
    } catch (Exception E) {
      // TODO: handle exception - couldn't load class in question
    }
  } // for

  // register detected classes with AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
  setAnnotatedClasses(classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]));
  return super.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

If you're not using Spring (and you should be :-) ) you can write your own code for detecting appropriate classes and register them with your `AnnotationConfiguration` via `addAnnotatedClass()` method.

Incidentally, it's not necessary to map packages unless you've actually declared something at package level.

Comment: Wow Chss, It is the first time i have seen ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider. Very good.

Answer (score 11):

I just come across this problem, and find out there seems an out of box solution for this. My integration is not out yet, will update this later.

From the Javadoc, especially the `packagesToScan` part:

> `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`
>
> Subclass of Spring's standard LocalSessionFactoryBean for Hibernate,
>   supporting JDK 1.5+ annotation metadata for mappings.
>
> Note: This class requires Hibernate 3.2 or later, with the Java
>   Persistence API and the Hibernate Annotations add-on present.
>
> Example for an `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` bean definition:
>
> ```xml
> <bean id="sessionFactory" 
>       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
>   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
>   <property name="annotatedClasses">
>     <list>
>       <value>test.package.Foo</value>
>       <value>test.package.Bar</value>
>     </list>
>   </property>
> </bean>
> ```
>
> Or when using classpath scanning for autodetection of entity classes:
>
> ```xml
> <bean id="sessionFactory"
>       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
>   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
>   <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>
> </bean>
> ```
>
> Since: 1.2.2
>   Author: Juergen Hoeller

Comment: <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>                     This worked for me too.. Thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 11):

Bit of thread necromancy here...

It still doesn't look like there's a good way to do what you want.  If you don't want to use Spring, here's a similar method using [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/):

```java
// Create your SessionFactory with mappings for every `Entity` in a specific package
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("your_hibernate.cfg.xml");

Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your_package");

Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.Entity.class);

for(Class<?> clazz : classes)
{
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

The same approach is probably viable for other Java reflection libraries.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this way of configuration doesn't work for Hibernate 5. It should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `spring` or any other library, you can achieve that like this. Same approach as [luke's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351985/381897) but without `Reflections` library

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.StandardLocation;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class SessionFactoryWrapper {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactoryWrapper(final String...packagesToScan) {
        this.sessionFactory = this.createSessionFactory(packagesToScan);
    }

    private SessionFactory createSessionFactory(final String[] packagesToScan) {
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure(); // Reads hibernate.cfg.xml from classpath

        for (String packageToScan : packagesToScan) {
            this.getEntityClasses(packageToScan).stream().forEach( configuration::addAnnotatedClass);
        }

        final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    private Collection<Class> getEntityClasses(final String pack) {
        final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        try {
            return StreamSupport.stream(fileManager.list(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, pack, Collections.singleton(JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS), false).spliterator(), false)
                    .map(FileObject::getName)
                    .map(name -> {
                        try {
                            final String[] split = name
                                    .replace(".class", "")
                                    .replace(")", "")
                                    .split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));

                            final String fullClassName = pack + "." + split[split.length - 1];
                            return Class.forName(fullClassName);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                    })
                    .filter(aClass -> aClass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done some investigations of class scanning approaches, using answers from StackOverflow. So I gather all it together, using a Hibernate entities scanning as a test, in the one test project: [hibernate-scanners-test](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-scanners-test).

**Using fluent-hibernate**

If you are looking for a quick scanning approach without additional dependencies, you can try [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) library (you will not need to have other jars, except the library).
Apart this, it has some useful features for Hibernate 5 and Hibernate 4, including entities scanning, a Hibernate 5 implicit naming strategy, a nested transformer and others.

Just download the library from the project page: [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) and use [EntityScanner](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/scanner/EntityScanner.java):

*For Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5:*

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
EntityScanner.scanPackages("my.com.entities", "my.com.other.entities")
    .addTo(configuration);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

*Using a new Hibernate 5 bootstrapping API:*

```
List<Class<?>> classes = EntityScanner
        .scanPackages("my.com.entities", "my.com.other.entities").result();

MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources();
for (Class<?> annotatedClass : classes) {
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
}

SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata()
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
1. XML
<mapping class="com.concretepage.Person"/>

2. Class
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);

            //Configure all the classes.

            Set<Class> entityClasses = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Person.class,PersonDetails.class));
//Iterate all the Classes.
            for (Class cls : entityClasses ) {
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(cls);
            }
3. Add package          
//Or you can add package
            configuration.addPackage("com.domain.entity");
```