# How to use hibernate annotation properly?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I just set up a basic hibernate/spring project to test some stuff. I use a MySQL db by using WAMP.

These are all of the classes: http://codepaste.net/7pwmtx

This is my bean definition and pom file: http://codepaste.net/4iz7jb

POM is a little bit messy but this is the problem: I think that I set up my dialect properly because I get no errors when i add something to the db. I get errors when I use find in hql. I t seems like hibernate isnt retrieving data from the same place that it is putting it. Any idea why this doesnt work?

By the way, the console output was:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: hobject is not mapped [from hobject]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: hobject is not mapped [from hobject]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:660)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
    at hibernate.dao.SpringHibernateOperatorImplementation.getAllRows(SpringHibernateOperatorImplementation.java:24)
    at hibernate.main.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: hobject is not mapped [from hobject]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:914)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: This error means you haven't inform which classes should hibernate manage, or at least there is no class named hobject managed by hibernate, please paste your configuration here

Comment: It is supposed to be configured by the annotation so I don't use a configuration file. Look in the .xml file and you'll see that I use annotations for that and that I set the properties in the beandefinitionfile.

Comment: but why are you using  String hql = "from hobject" instead of "from HObject"?

Comment: Tried HOBJECT HObject and hobject, same result for all three....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the entity class **hibernate.dao.HObject** to hibernate.cfg.xml files. It is neeeded even if you are using annotation based configurations.

If you want to skip adding these to cfg file you can use the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419802/hibernate-configuration-session-factory-scanning/7671247#7671247) provided you are using **spring**.