# Hibernate configuration error - one to many relation using annotation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I have gone through many videos and tutorials explaining about how to configure one to many relation in hibernate using annotation mechanism. Still I am getting this error.

the error is : 
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.Professor.coursesAssigned[bean.Course]
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.Professor.coursesAssigned[bean.Course]

My classes are :

Professor.java

```
    package bean;

    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    @Entity
    public class Professor extends User{

        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Course.class, mappedBy = "assignedProfessor", 
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set<Course> coursesAssigned;
    }
```

and course.java is :

```
    package bean;

    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

    public class Course {

        private Integer courseId;
        private String courseName;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Professor.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "professor_join")
        private Professor assignedProfessor;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.Professor.coursesAssigned[bean.Course] 
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.Professor.coursesAssigned[bean.Course]
```

The exception has already explained the causes . `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` can only be annotated on the property whose class is a mapped class. A class is considered as mapped if they are annotated with  `@Entity` and is included as [`<mapping class>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413190/hibernate-mapping-package) in the configuration file or [programmatically included in the Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAnnotatedClass%28java.lang.Class%29) instance.

So , I believe the exception will be gone after you mark `@Entity` on the class `Course`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. That really worked.. It just slipped out of my mind.