# How to dynamically scan Annotated classes using google Reflections?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflections

In refrence to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime). I am making an hibernate demo in which I want to map all the POJO classes dynamically. I found the above given reference and tried to scan my classes from the package mapping only. But it is giving some errors like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
at com.telemune.util.StringUtil.getSessionFactory(StringUtil.java:44)
at com.telemune.generator.TableDescriber.describeTable(TableDescriber.java:33)
at com.telemune.generator.PojoGenerator.main(PojoGenerator.java:169)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 3 more
```

when I added **com.google.common_1.0.0.201004262004.jar** I got this:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:358)
at com.telemune.util.StringUtil.getSessionFactory(StringUtil.java:46)
at com.telemune.generator.TableDescriber.describeTable(TableDescriber.java:33)
at com.telemune.generator.PojoGenerator.main(PojoGenerator.java:169)
```

I am not able to ask or comment there that's why I am asking it here specially to @MartinAubele, @Jonathan, @SergeyBrunov, @ArthurRonald. Please give an example or something by which I can use google-reflections to scan my package.

Please **Note:** I don't want to use Spring. So please don't suggest about that. Thanks in Advance.

some code Sample:

```
SessionFactory sfactory = null;
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=null;
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(PojoGenerator.pkgName);
Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.Entity.class);
for(Class<?> clazz : classes)
{
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

    sfactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

and **another problem** is :
**configuration.buildSessionFactory();** is not allowing me to use 
**configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);**

Comment: @luke sir please have a look you answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413190/hibernate-mapping-package). please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a valid version of the `Reflections` library:

`reflections-0.9.10.jar`

with dependencies:

`com.google.guava:guava:18.0`,

`org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA`,

`com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.1`

A dependencies list can be found there: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10

Or just using Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The library source and documentation: [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

I have a project with tests for various libraries from answers on StackOverflow (like the link is provided by you):

[hibernate-scanners-test](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-scanners-test)

An example using `Reflections`: [ReflectionsLibrary.java](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-scanners-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/ladynev/scanners/ReflectionsLibrary.java)

A test class for all libraries: [ScannersTest.java](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-scanners-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/ladynev/scanners/ScannersTest.java)

**Update**

To fix

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl`

you just need a valid set of the Hibernate libraries. For an example, for Hibernate 4.3.5: [libs_h4](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql/tree/master/libs_h4)

Comment: I think the code proceed from reflections  but stuck here:

Comment: that is : serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
  
  **sfactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);**

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means that you have incorrect library versions.

Comment: sir as I said Two problems are there: **1.** I am not able to use **new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).bu‌​ild(); ** I says **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl** . **2.** when I use this code: **session.beginTransaction();

   String query = "select c from " + name + " c";
   System.out.println(query);

   hql = session.createQuery(query);** It returns a null list.

Comment: these are my hibernate libraries: annotations-2.0.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar,
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,
dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
guava-18.0.jar,
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar,
hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar,
hibernate-core-4.3.0.beta1.jar,
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.Final.jar,
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar,
jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar,
javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar,
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar,
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar,
mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar,
ojdbc14.jar,
postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar,
reflections-0.9.10.jar. I am using multiple DBs.

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj I update. And, please, use Maven or Gradle. You will not have such problems.

Comment: I have asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211621/google-reflections-when-should-reflections-library-be-used-and-how-to-create) question in reference to this question please have a look sir.