# Hibernate Mapping Exception error: Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate

While learning Hibernate and associated design patterns (https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-dao-example/) I am facing an issue with `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.mavenproject1.entity.Book`.

Using latest Hibernate with an embedded HSQLDB for study purposes.

Using annotated entity file

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;
...
```

bookDAO

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    try {
        // Build a SessionFactory object from session-factory config
        // defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("Error in creating SessionFactory object."
                + e.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}

public void persist(Book entity) {
    getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

BookService

```
public void persist(Book entity) {
    bookDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    bookDao.persist(entity);
    bookDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
}
```

App

```
BookService bookService = new BookService();
Book book1 = new Book("1", "The Brothers Karamazov", "Fyodor Dostoevsky");
bookService.persist(book1);
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<mapping package="com.mycompany.mavenproject1.entity"/>
```

I am not able to figure out why that exception is thrown.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it's noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413190/hibernate-mapping-package):

> The `<mapping package="..."/>` entry is for configuring meta-data defined on the package itself, not for classes in that package.

So, you should use some solutions proposed in the mentioned question or expliсitly provide a list of all entities in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```xml
<mapping class="com.mycompany.mavenproject1.entity.Book"/>
<!--  other entities  -->
```

Comment: have tried that one as well but gives me same error message.

Comment: Do you use `@javax.persistence.Entity` annotation on the `Book`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I put.

Answer (score 0):

found a hint since Hibernate 5.x there have been changes implemented.

with this code the tutorial is working fine.

```
StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure()
                .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
                .getMetadataBuilder()
                .build();

        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```